# Find and Replace Multiple srings with different values in zapier

Tags: zapier

I have a zap that gets a block of text. Within that block of text they are about 30 variables that I need to replace e.g.{{variable1}}, {{variable2}}, {{variable3}} etc.
I need to replace each of these variables with a different string that I get in another step of the zap.

Zapier has a tool called find and replace text which works well; however it only works for 1 string at a time so this would mean I would need to do this 30 times.

Is there  a way to complete this is one or two steps. Is it possible to use Code by Zapier (either Python or JS) to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yep! This can be done very easily using a code step in Python:

You'll pass any data into the Code step in the `input_data` dict. I'm not sure how it's coming in or formatted, but hopefully you can build a `dict` out of it. I'll make one up in this example.

```py
keys = input_data['keys'] # something like "{{a}},{{b}},{{c}}"
values = input_data['values'] # something like "1,2,3"

replacers = {k:v for k,v in zip(keys.split(','), values.split(','))} # makes a mapping like {"{{a}}": "1", ...}

str_to_replace = input_data['string_to_repalace']
for k, v in replacers.items():
    str_to_replace = str_to_replace.replace(k, v)

return {'result': str_to_replace}
```

How exactly this fits your use case depends on how your variables and stuff come in, but it should get you most of the way there.